# Quill Can't find case class property

Tags: scala, macros, abstract-syntax-tree, quill, zio

Writing simple CRUD application using ZIO & Quill

Domain model consists of User and Roles (One to Many)

When trying to invoke method on one of the Entities lifted in the quill context (or obtained in a process of building a query) I'm facing compile time exception:

```
Can't find case class property: typedCode
                roleSchema.filter(r => r.typedCode == lift(roleCode)).take(1)
```

```scala
val dc: db.Ctx.type = db.Ctx
import dc._


def findRoleByCode(roleCode: RoleCode): Result[Option[Role]] =
    dc.run(
        roleSchema.filter(r => r.typedCode == lift(roleCode)).take(1)
    ).map(_.headOption)
```

Schema as follows:

User Entity

```scala
case class User(
    id: String,
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    age: Int
){
    def typedId: UserId = UserId(id)
}
```

Role Entity

```scala
case class Role(
    code: String,
    name: String
){
    def typedCode: RoleCode = RoleCode(code)
}
```

User To Role Association and Value Classes for identifiers

```scala
case class UserToRole(roleId: RoleCode, userId: UserId)

case class RoleCode(code: String) extends AnyVal
case class UserId(id: String) extends AnyVal
```

The conclusion that I currently have that it's not possible to invoke methods on entities present in the Quill context. I suppose it's due to macro evaluation and some kind of type replacement

The thing is - getting properties is not a problem. I can obtain `role.code` as a `String`, but can not invoke `.typedCode`. Same applies to User

**Edit**

Trying converting `.typedCode` and `.typedId` to methods that accept `Unit` as a parameter `typedCode(): RoleCode` `typedId(): UserId` results in another exception:

```
Tree 'r.typedCode()' can't be parsed to 'Ast'
                roleSchema.filter(r => r.typedCode() == lift(roleCode)).take(1)
```

**Edit 2**
Building instances of value classes in a query: `RoleCode(r.code)` results in:

```
exception during macro expansion: 
scala.reflect.macros.TypecheckException: package module4.homework.dao.entity is not a value
    at scala.reflect.macros.contexts.Typers.$anonfun$typecheck$3(Typers.scala:44)
    at scala.reflect.macros.contexts.Typers.$anonfun$typecheck$2(Typers.scala:38)
    at scala.reflect.macros.contexts.Typers.doTypecheck$1(Typers.scala:37)
    at scala.reflect.macros.contexts.Typers.$anonfun$typecheck$7(Typers.scala:50)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.wrappingIntoTerm(Trees.scala:1891)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.wrappingIntoTerm$(Trees.scala:1888)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.wrappingIntoTerm(SymbolTable.scala:28)
    at scala.reflect.macros.contexts.Typers.typecheck(Typers.scala:50)
    at scala.reflect.macros.contexts.Typers.typecheck$(Typers.scala:32)
    at scala.reflect.macros.contexts.Context.typecheck(Context.scala:18)
    at scala.reflect.macros.contexts.Context.typecheck(Context.scala:18)
    at io.getquill.quotation.Parsing$$anonfun$propertyParser$1.applyOrElse(Parsing.scala:540)
    at io.getquill.quotation.Parsing$$anonfun$propertyParser$1.applyOrElse(Parsing.scala:526)
    at scala.PartialFunction$Lifted.apply(PartialFunction.scala:338)
    at scala.PartialFunction$Lifted.apply(PartialFunction.scala:334)
    at io.getquill.quotation.Parsing$Parser.unapply(Parsing.scala:44)
    at io.getquill.quotation.Parsing$$anonfun$astParser$1.applyOrElse(Parsing.scala:64)
    at io.getquill.quotation.Parsing$$anonfun$astParser$1.applyOrElse(Parsing.scala:48)
    at scala.PartialFunction$Lifted.apply(PartialFunction.scala:338)
    at scala.PartialFunction$Lifted.apply(PartialFunction.scala:334)
    at io.getquill.quotation.Parsing$Parser.unapply(Parsing.scala:44)
    at io.getquill.quotation.Parsing$Parser.apply(Parsing.scala:35)
    at io.getquill.quotation.Parsing$$anonfun$propertyParser$1.applyOrElse(Parsing.scala:546)
    at io.getquill.quotation.Parsing$$anonfun$propertyParser$1.applyOrElse(Parsing.scala:526)
    at scala.PartialFunction$Lifted.apply(PartialFunction.scala:338)
    at scala.PartialFunction$Lifted.apply(PartialFunction.scala:334)
    at io.getquill.quotation.Parsing$Parser.unapply(Parsing.scala:44)
    at io.getquill.quotation.Parsing$$anonfun$astParser$1.applyOrElse(Parsing.scala:64)
    at io.getquill.quotation.Parsing$$anonfun$astParser$1.applyOrElse(Parsing.scala:48)
    at scala.PartialFunction$Lifted.apply(PartialFunction.scala:338)
    at scala.PartialFunction$Lifted.apply(PartialFunction.scala:334)
    at io.getquill.quotation.Parsing$Parser.unapply(Parsing.scala:44)
    at io.getquill.quotation.Parsing$$anonfun$functionApplyParser$1.applyOrElse(Parsing.scala:579)
    at io.getquill.quotation.Parsing$$anonfun$functionApplyParser$1.applyOrElse(Parsing.scala:578)
    at scala.PartialFunction$Lifted.apply(PartialFunction.scala:338)
    at scala.PartialFunction$Lifted.apply(PartialFunction.scala:334)
    at io.getquill.quotation.Parsing$Parser.unapply(Parsing.scala:44)
    at io.getquill.quotation.Parsing$$anonfun$operationParser$1.applyOrElse(Parsing.scala:558)
    at io.getquill.quotation.Parsing$$anonfun$operationParser$1.applyOrElse(Parsing.scala:552)
    at scala.PartialFunction$Lifted.apply(PartialFunction.scala:338)
    at scala.PartialFunction$Lifted.apply(PartialFunction.scala:334)
    at io.getquill.quotation.Parsing$Parser.unapply(Parsing.scala:44)
    at io.getquill.quotation.Parsing$$anonfun$astParser$1.applyOrElse(Parsing.scala:61)
    at io.getquill.quotation.Parsing$$anonfun$astParser$1.applyOrElse(Parsing.scala:48)
    at scala.PartialFunction$Lifted.apply(PartialFunction.scala:338)
    at scala.PartialFunction$Lifted.apply(PartialFunction.scala:334)
    at io.getquill.quotation.Parsing$Parser.unapply(Parsing.scala:44)
    at io.getquill.quotation.Parsing$Parser.apply(Parsing.scala:35)
    at io.getquill.quotation.Parsing.io$getquill$quotation$Parsing$$equalityWithInnerTypechecksIdiomatic(Parsing.scala:603)
    at io.getquill.quotation.Parsing$$anonfun$equalityOperationParser$1.applyOrElse(Parsing.scala:624)
    at io.getquill.quotation.Parsing$$anonfun$equalityOperationParser$1.applyOrElse(Parsing.scala:622)
    at scala.PartialFunction$Lifted.apply(PartialFunction.scala:338)
    at scala.PartialFunction$Lifted.apply(PartialFunction.scala:334)
    at io.getquill.quotation.Parsing$Parser.unapply(Parsing.scala:44)
    at io.getquill.quotation.Parsing$$anonfun$operationParser$1.applyOrElse(Parsing.scala:553)
    at io.getquill.quotation.Parsing$$anonfun$operationParser$1.applyOrElse(Parsing.scala:552)
    at scala.PartialFunction$Lifted.apply(PartialFunction.scala:338)
    at scala.PartialFunction$Lifted.apply(PartialFunction.scala:334)
    at io.getquill.quotation.Parsing$Parser.unapply(Parsing.scala:44)
    at io.getquill.quotation.Parsing$$anonfun$astParser$1.applyOrElse(Parsing.scala:61)
    at io.getquill.quotation.Parsing$$anonfun$astParser$1.applyOrElse(Parsing.scala:48)
    at scala.PartialFunction$Lifted.apply(PartialFunction.scala:338)
    at scala.PartialFunction$Lifted.apply(PartialFunction.scala:334)
    at io.getquill.quotation.Parsing$Parser.unapply(Parsing.scala:44)
    at io.getquill.quotation.Parsing$Parser.apply(Parsing.scala:35)
    at io.getquill.quotation.Parsing$$anonfun$queryParser$1.applyOrElse(Parsing.scala:202)
    at io.getquill.quotation.Parsing$$anonfun$queryParser$1.applyOrElse(Parsing.scala:187)
    at scala.PartialFunction$Lifted.apply(PartialFunction.scala:338)
    at scala.PartialFunction$Lifted.apply(PartialFunction.scala:334)
    at io.getquill.quotation.Parsing$Parser.unapply(Parsing.scala:44)
    at io.getquill.quotation.Parsing$$anonfun$astParser$1.applyOrElse(Parsing.scala:50)
    at io.getquill.quotation.Parsing$$anonfun$astParser$1.applyOrElse(Parsing.scala:48)
    at scala.PartialFunction$Lifted.apply(PartialFunction.scala:338)
    at scala.PartialFunction$Lifted.apply(PartialFunction.scala:334)
    at io.getquill.quotation.Parsing$Parser.unapply(Parsing.scala:44)
    at io.getquill.quotation.Parsing$Parser.apply(Parsing.scala:35)
    at io.getquill.quotation.Parsing$$anonfun$queryParser$1.applyOrElse(Parsing.scala:230)
    at io.getquill.quotation.Parsing$$anonfun$queryParser$1.applyOrElse(Parsing.scala:187)
    at scala.PartialFunction$Lifted.apply(PartialFunction.scala:338)
    at scala.PartialFunction$Lifted.apply(PartialFunction.scala:334)
    at io.getquill.quotation.Parsing$Parser.unapply(Parsing.scala:44)
    at io.getquill.quotation.Parsing$$anonfun$astParser$1.applyOrElse(Parsing.scala:50)
    at io.getquill.quotation.Parsing$$anonfun$astParser$1.applyOrElse(Parsing.scala:48)
    at scala.PartialFunction$Lifted.apply(PartialFunction.scala:338)
    at scala.PartialFunction$Lifted.apply(PartialFunction.scala:334)
    at io.getquill.quotation.Parsing$Parser.unapply(Parsing.scala:44)
    at io.getquill.quotation.Parsing$Parser.apply(Parsing.scala:35)
    at io.getquill.quotation.Quotation.$anonfun$quote$1(Quotation.scala:28)
    at io.getquill.util.Interpolator$Traceable.andReturn(Interpolator.scala:145)
    at io.getquill.quotation.Quotation.quote(Quotation.scala:28)
    at io.getquill.quotation.Quotation.quote$(Quotation.scala:24)
    at io.getquill.dsl.QuotationMacro.quote(QuotationDsl.scala:34)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor61.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at scala.reflect.macros.runtime.JavaReflectionRuntimes$JavaReflectionResolvers.$anonfun$resolveJavaReflectionRuntime$5(JavaReflectionRuntimes.scala:45)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Macros.macroExpandWithRuntime(Macros.scala:770)

                roleSchema.filter(r => RoleCode(r.code) == lift(roleCode)).take(1)
```

**Edit 3**
I suppose it's stated by design that we can't invoke methods from the query context.

The only solution that resolves most of the problems is changing domain model itself and using Value Classes as case class parameters for the `User` and `Role`

Comment: How should `RoleCode(code)` be represented in SQL when you're doing: `.filter(r => r.typedCode() == lift(roleCode)).take(1)`? That's why it says: `r.typedCode() can't be parsed to 'Ast'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already answered in the comment, Quill will translate fields and case classes to the selected SQL dialect. There isn't a way to translate `RoleCode(code)` to SQL. You should be able to make `typedRole` and `typedCode` a field of the case class and handle that through overriding `apply` method for this particular case class.